# EMF in a single moving wire in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

Suppose we have a single open circuit wire, moving with speed $v$ inside an infinite and uniform magnetic field $B$. Wire has a length of $L$ and it moves perpendicular to magnetic field. In this case Lorentz force is used to calculate
the EMF created in wire and it is:
$$EMF=vBL$$

We know that this formula is derived using **Lorentz force** and also **Lorentz force** can be deduced from **Maxwell-Faraday** equation ([explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lorentz_force#Lorentz_force_and_Faraday.27s_law_of_induction)), so can we obtain the same above formula using **Maxwell-Faraday** equation?

$$∮_cE.dl=−\frac{d}{dt}∬_sB.ds$$

If yes, how ? Also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_paradox) says that **Faraday's law** of induction can not be applied to a single wire:

> The induced electromotive force in any closed circuit is equal to the
> negative of the time rate of change of the magnetic flux enclosed by
> the circuit.
>
> This version of Faraday's law strictly holds only when the closed
> circuit is a loop of infinitely thin wire, and is invalid in other
> circumstances.

Comment: What is Maxwell-Faraday equation? How would you derive Lorentz force from it?

Comment: @JánLalinský Added one link and Maxwell-Faraday equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, with can show it with Maxwell-faraday equation:
$$∮_cE.dl= -\frac{d}{dt} ∬_sB.ds$$

We can suppose a contour with rectangular shape that our wire is one side of it. the wire side is moving and other side is constant so the area of contour is growing with V speed and if we write Maxwell-Faraday equation for this contour we have:
[image]
$$
emf=- \frac{d}{dt} ∬_sB.ds=  -\frac{d}{dt}  ∬_sB.dx.dy= -BL  \frac{d}{dt}  ∫dx=-BL  \frac{d}{dt}  (x)=-VBL $$

Comment: If the width of the rectangular is fixed, $\frac{d}{dt}∫dx$ becomes zero. Therefore one side must be fixed and the other side (the wire) must be moving to have a time changing width.

Comment: yes your right my suppose was wrong so if we consider your correction then can show that the result is  the same.